# Error:Object Expected

Tags: extjs

Iam trying to store the state in thedb through webservice.

Iam using Http State Provider to do so.

Iam getting an error in the following line saying object expected.
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.HttpProvider({ url: 'GetGridState.asmx/readdata' }));

Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use firebug or even alerts if nothing else to see if maybe you're not passing an object where you should be.

Comment: Iam getting the following error in firebug saying

Ext.state.HttpProvider is not a constructor

Comment: xrx215 - it sounds then like your version of ExtJS doesn't include HttpProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct version of ExtJS? It looks like there is no more `Ext.state.HttpProvider` in ExtJS 3.1.

Comment: Iam making use of  following thread to do this.

http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?p=424107#post424107

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have not included the HttpStateProvider class code correctly, or included it after the code that is trying to use it.  Double-check that if you are referring to an external js file, it is loaded properly and in the right order.